# Display 2d matrix on the page using a servlet

Tags: servlets

I have a scenario, wherein I need to display a matrix box in the browser as an output. I am taking an input from the page, do some business logic and the output of that logic will be a Matrix which I need to show on the page. I can see the output in console but in the browser I see this matrix in one line. Please help me out.
Piece of code using servlet :

```
out.println("Matrix");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
       {
      for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) 
             {`enter code here`
        out.print(matrix[i][j] + " ");
          }
              out.print("\n");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Browsers want to see HTML instead of just text. Add newlines with `out.print("<br/>")`, or add `out.print("<pre>");` as the first output, or output a Content-Type header saying the content is text/plain.

Comment: Thank you so much. This actually worked indeed. Can I use table to display the matrix?

Comment: Output is showing in the other page. I want the output to be in same page. Let me know thanks

Comment: You don't specify what "other page" or how the input is handled. To guestimate: use an IFRAME tag or use AJAX to dynamically modify the page.